# What would a theoretical non-rotational artificial gravity generator look like?

Tags: gravity, gravitational-waves

Assuming we invented a device that can create gravitational waves or bend spacetime (**or through any non-motion related phenomenon**) and produce artificial gravity, would it pull everything towards a center of mass like real gravity does?  Or would it be more like two plates that push things away from one and towards the other similar to how electrical fields in charged plates work.

Does one violate the laws of physics more than the other does?

[image: Hypothetical Artificial Gravity Devices]

Comment: Accelerating reference frames do this.

Comment: To reopen this post (v1) consider to include your definition of [artificial gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity) (and how it differs from gravity) if you don't mean the effect of using an accelerating reference frame.

Comment: @Qmechanic its right there "or through any other non-motion related phenomenon"